# Formula Not Saving in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I keep trying to update a formula inside Process Builder from today() to today()+5 and it does not save. Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: Try with **TODAY()+5**

Comment: Do you have any error message that can help us guide you ? Maybe [this answer](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DbY6QAK) can also help you

Comment: No error comes up, it actually looks like it saves correctly, but when you go back into the process, the formula is back to what it was.

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the correct version of the process builder;  are you making the changes through the Setup Menu > Process Buulder ui? or through the metadata api?